# Does Views cache row entity?

Tags: 7, views, entities, caching

I have a Views of users.

Does user_load($row->id); will load a user from cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

[`user_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7) leverages a per-request cache.  This is implemented as a static cache in the entity controller (see the [`DrupalDefaultEntityController`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/DrupalDefaultEntityController/7) class).  So, if the same user is loaded multiple times during the same request, the subsequent loads will come from the static cache.

In a base install, entities are not cached between requests.  But, fields attached to entities are cached in the `cache_field` bin.

Data for views may or may not be cached, depending on your global Views settings and overrides for a particular view.

If you have the [Entity Cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache) module installed, then entities are cached between requests in whatever backend you have defined.  There are almost no reasons to not have this module installed on a site.  It provides huge performance improvements, especially with non-SQL cache backends.

Answer (score 0):

It should load from the cache, if the object is set there.

As defined in the API:

```
user_load($uid, $reset = FALSE)
```

$reset will by default force loading from the cache.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7

Hope this helps!